# Is stateless state cleared after its job?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class DefaultStatelessService implements StatelessService {

    private Object o;

}
```

where I use provate field `o` in few private methods. The question is: after the stateless will finish it's job will its state be cleared?

For example:

1. Stateless instance has been taken from pool.
2. State of private field `o` has been changed during stateless job.
3. Stateless instance has been returned to pool.
4. Some other operation taken the same stateless instance and want to use it - is object `o` in the same state as before or it has been cleared?

Comment: Why does your stateless service have a state?

Comment: I did it in this way because few private methods use this object so I though it will be easier to use it as private field than each method parameter.

Comment: I don't think the field will be cleared, however you musn't store a data related to a specific user in a stateless EJB. This other question might give you some information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351220/stateless-and-stateful-enterprise-java-beans.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely upon any state stored in a stateless session bean between method invocations.

Some container implementations may not even bother to use a pool - it will just give you a new instance each time.

In your example there is nothing that will explicitly clear "o", but it's quite possible the entire bean instance will be discarded.